# SPRING, JPA(EclipseLink) with JTA Transaction Manager(JBoss 7) - NOT Committing to Database

Tags: spring, jpa, eclipselink, jboss7.x, jta

I have created an example - SPRING, JPA(EclipseLink persistence provider) with JTA Transaction Manager(JBoss 7). I have observed that all the data in database is being shown in UI properly for the read operations. But when it comes to save/update or delete operation the services layer is not committing the work to database. No exception is caught(I have checked the console/log too and also debugged the code where I can see entityManager.persist/remove is being invoked without any exception).

--Code Listing-- 
1. Datasource configuration in standalone.xml

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/mysql_customerdb3" pool-name="mysql_customerdb3_pool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customerdb</connection-url>
            <driver>mysql</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>root</user-name>
                <password>root</password>
            </security>
            <statement>
                <prepared-statement-cache-size>10</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
            </statement>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
```

1. Database driver configuration in module.xml
2. persistence.xml

   org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
       java:/mysql_customerdb3
       com.springforbeginners.model.Customer
3. customerdispatcher-servlet.xml

   ```
   <context:annotation-config />
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.springforbeginners" />

   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
       <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
       <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
       <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
       <property name="loadTimeWeaver" ref="loadTimeWeaver" />
       <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="loadTimeWeaver" class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleLoadTimeWeaver" >
   </bean>

   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
       <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:jboss/TransactionManager"/>
       <property name="userTransactionName" value="java:jboss/UserTransaction"/>
   </bean> 

   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
   ```
4. CustomerServiceImpl.java

   package com.springforbeginners.service;

   import com.springforbeginners.dao.CustomerDAO;
   import com.springforbeginners.model.Customer;
   import java.util.List;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
   import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

   @Service
   public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {
       @Autowired
       private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

   ```
   @Transactional
   @Override
   public void addCustomer(Customer customer) {
       customerDAO.addCustomer(customer);
   }

   @Transactional
   @Override
   public List<Customer> listCustomer() {
       return customerDAO.listCustomer();
   }

   @Transactional
   @Override
   public void removeCustomer(Integer customerId) {
       customerDAO.removeCustomer(customerId);
   }
   ```

   }
5. CustomerDAOImpl.java

   package com.springforbeginners.dao;

   import com.springforbeginners.model.Customer;
   import java.util.List;
   import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
   import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

   @Repository
   public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {
       @PersistenceContext(unitName="CustomerDetailsPU3")
       private EntityManager entityManager;

   ```
   @Override
   public void addCustomer(Customer customer) {
       entityManager.persist(customer);
   }

   @Override
   public List<Customer> listCustomer() {
       return entityManager.createQuery("select c from Customer c", Customer.class).getResultList();
   }

   @Override
   public void removeCustomer(Integer customerId) {
       Customer customer = (Customer) entityManager.getReference(Customer.class, customerId);
       if (null != customer) {
           entityManager.remove(customer);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

---

I do not know what and where exactly is something missing. But with the above code the read operations are working as expected. Problem is with save operations. I have converted the above example to use non-JTA datasource(also modified standalone.xml for jta=false) and to use JpaTransactionManager as below

With non-JTA datasource and 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager' all operations(read as well as save/update/delete) are working fine.

But the JTA version of my example is not working as expected(save operations not committing work to database). Any help/pointers appreciated.

Thanks
Prakash

---

James,

I will be running this application on JBoss. But one datasource on JBoss and other on Glassfish and transaction should span save operation on both datasources simultaneously. This is what I am trying to achieve. I have a web application including spring for service(data) layer currently running on JBoss.

As you said earlier - I will have two persistence.xmls one for JBoss and one for Glassfish. As I am doing this first time I was/am in doubt whether the transaction(that spans two datasources on different servers-in this case JBoss and Glassfish), can this be executed entirely by JBoss(in case if the entire business logic resides in serviceImpl class deployed on JBoss)? In this case I will be using JBoss transaction manager( property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:jboss/TransactionManager" ). Is this sufficient or do I need to similarly have Glassfish transaction manager too? Sorry if this has created the confusion.

Another question from me was that is there a provision for speifying jndi ports in persistence.xml/anywhere else?(Definitely I will have two different persistence.xmls and I will mention the target server as JBoss in one and as Glassfish in another).

Do we have a technique in spring by which business logic can be distributed across different servers like JBoss/Glassfish and still under one single transatcion? I did not know if this can be an option. Were u talking about this scenario in which it will require two different deployment scripts one for each server?

Thanks
Prakash

Comment: Missed database driver configuration in module.xml. Listing below...2. Database driver configuration in module.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>

Answer (score 2):

What is your persistence.xml?

Since you are using JTA, you must define the "eclipselink.target-server"="JBoss"

Answer (score 1):

My persistence.xml(modified) now looks like below. Added target server property in persistence.xml. This solved the problem.

```
  <persistence-unit name="CustomerDetailsPU3" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/mysql_customerdb3</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.springforbeginners.model.Customer</class>
    <properties>
          <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="JBoss" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

Thanks
Prakash